# How to change the labels font size

Tags: address-labels, printing

I don't find how to change the font size when I print labels (I have a CiviCRM Spark account). The default size is far too small and the Post office don't accept it...

Answer (score 3):

Yes there is a option to change the font size. The UI setting is not user friendly but it does allow you to update the attributes.

1. Navigate to CiviCRM >> Administer >> System Settings >> Option Groups.
2. Find for Mailing Label Format.
3. Click on "Edit options' link besides 'Mailing Label Format'
4. You will see list of formats, click on 'Edit' besides one of the format type.
5. In 'value' text field find for 'font-size' and change the value from old to new

for eg if the old value was `"font-size":8` than replace it with `"font-size":16`

HTH

Pradeep

Comment: Thx a lot, Pradeep! However, my problem was another: I would like to change the font size of just a part of the label (1 row with a token that is NOT part of the address). If I change the font size, all the rows are the same size anyway... I tried to put some php / html codes in the "Mailing label format", but it doesn't work...